# Не могу запустить файл sh

Tags: macos, sh

```
sh Script.sh --delay 0.3 —id "9926*****" —token "2*****************"
```

Пишет Cannot execute binary file

Запускаю на Mac

Ps. Запускал на Windows, работало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что выводит команда `file Script.sh`? Также покажите вывод `head Script.sh`

Comment: Это и  в самом деле не файл с шелловским скриптом (именно такой вид файла ожидает /bin/sh), о чем и сказала команда `file`. Запустить его таким образом не получится.

Comment: @avp а как его запустить?

Comment: Мне кажется, что на Mac-е его никак не получится запустить (если только из какого-то интерпретаторо винды (или из виртуальной машины с установленной виндой))

Comment: @avp Я его перемеименовывал из exe в sh, может, надо по другому делать?

Comment: Смена имен (расширений) на результат не повлияет

Comment: @avp Я понимаю, но может надо конвертитовать в sh по другому?

Comment: sh -- это не имя. Это текст, состоящий из команд интерпретатора sh. А у вас бинарный код (он должен исполняться  непосредственно процессором под управлением ОС). Но этот бинарный файл "отформатирован" таким образом, что он может быть выполнен под Windows на intel-совместимом процессоре. И с форматом бинарных файлов, который понимает Mac, этот файл не совместим. Надеюсь, что после такого количества букв, проблема стала вам понятна.

Comment: Если есть исходники exe и код кроссплатформенный, можете попробовать скомпилировать для мака

Comment: Думаю, лучше будет, если вы сами этому научитесь (здесь не freelance биржа)

Comment: @avp Спасибо, стало понятно